# Best way to perform arbitrary operations on groups with Dask DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dask, dask-dataframe

I want to use Dask for operations of the form

```py
df.groupby(some_columns).apply(some_function)
```

where `some_function()` may compute some summary statistics, perform timeseries forecasting, or even just save the group to a single file in AWS S3.

Dask [documentation](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/generated/dask.dataframe.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply.html#dask.dataframe.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply) states (and several other StackOverflow answers cite) that groupby-apply is not appropriate for aggregations:

> Pandas’ groupby-apply can be used to to apply arbitrary functions, including aggregations that result in one row per group. Dask’s groupby-apply will apply func once to each partition-group pair, so when func is a reduction you’ll end up with one row per partition-group pair. To apply a custom aggregation with Dask, use dask.dataframe.groupby.Aggregation.

It is not clear whether `Aggregation` supports operations on multiple columns.  However, [this DataFrames tutorial](https://examples.dask.org/dataframes/02-groupby.html#Groupby-Apply) seems to do exactly what I'm suggesting, with roughly `some_function = lambda x: LinearRegression().fit(...)`.  The example seems to work as intended, and I've similarly had no problems so far with e.g. `some_function = lambda x: x.to_csv(...)`.

Under what conditions can I expect that `some_function` will be passed all rows of the group?  If this is never guaranteed, is there a way to break the `LinearRegression` example?  And most importantly, what is the best way to handle these use cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the current version of documentation and the source code are not in sync. Specifically, in the source code for `dask.groupby`, there is this message:

> Dask groupby supports reductions, i.e., mean, sum and alike, and apply. The former do not shuffle the data and are efficiently implemented as tree reductions. The latter is implemented by shuffling the underlying partiitons such that all items of a group can be found in the same parititon.

This is not consistent with the warning in the docs about `partition-group`. The snippet below and task graph visualization also show that there is shuffling of data to ensure that partitions contain all members of the same group:

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'group': [0,0,1,1,2,0,1,2], 'npeople': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]})
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)

def myfunc(df):
    return df['npeople'].sum()

results_pandas = df.groupby('group').apply(myfunc).sort_index()
results_dask = ddf.groupby('group').apply(myfunc).compute().sort_index()

print(sum(results_dask != results_pandas))
# will print 0, so there are no differences
# between dask and pandas groupby
```

Comment: Thanks @SultanOrazbayev for pointing this out, the docs have been fixed in [this PR](https://github.com/dask/dask/pull/8507).

Answer (score 0):

This is speculative, but maybe one way to work around the scenario where `partition-group` leads to rows from a single group split across partitions is to explicitly re-partition the data in a way that ensures each group is associated with a unique partition.

One way to achieve that is by creating an index that is the same as the group identifier column. This in general is not a [cheap operation](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/generated/dask.dataframe.DataFrame.set_index.html), but it can be helped by pre-processing the data in a way that the group identifier is already sorted.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It makes sense that explicit re-partitioning can guarantee the desired behavior. But I'm still at a loss for when groupby-apply will split groups. Is there a way I can trigger such splitting on purpose, to study it in more detail?